# Weird artifacts in CocoonJS Path Demo

Tags: cocoonjs, two.js

Im getting some weird effect while zooming out in CocoonJS's Path Demo. (Iconia A510). Thethere are missing pixels from the rectangle. If i zoom back it looks solid again (but very pixxelated). Can someone confirm that this happens on other device too?

[image: CocoonJs Path Demo]

**Addendum**

I guess this is related to the smae problem. The very same test code run on CocoonJS (same device) and on Win 7 / Chrome 30.0.1599.66 m

[image: compare]

Here is an another test from a Nexus 7

https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/220033/1242079/0003f2e2-2a31-11e3-8c53-282493a462a9.png

*More info on TwoJS's github: https://github.com/jonobr1/two.js/issues/48*

Answer (score 0):

As CocoonJS doesn't have AntiAliasing, the problem is that your device doesn't have enough DPIs to render te entire path, there is no much to do on this because is a limitation on your tablet....

Comment: 149 dpi should be enough, shouldnt be? But CocoonJS.App.getDeviceInfo returns dpi:1, what cant be true.